# Bounded sequences on free ultrafilter

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory

Let $\mathcal U$ be a free (non-principal) ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$.

Two rational sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are called $\mathcal U$-equal if and only if $$\{n\mid a_n=b_n\}\in\mathcal U.$$
$(a_n)$ is called $\mathcal U$-bounded by some $M\in\mathbb Q$ if and only if
$$\{n\mid |a_n|<M\}\in\mathcal U.$$

To show: Every $\mathcal U$-bounded rational sequence is $\mathcal U$-equal to a monotone sequence.

I would like to show this only by using properties of the rational numbers, i.e. no completeness.

So far I thought the following might help:

Suppose $(a_n)$ is $\mathcal U$-bounded by $M$. Assume for a contradiction that it is not $\mathcal U$-equal to a monotone sequence.

Let $S_0:=\{n\mid |a_n|<M\}$. Since $(a_n)$ is bounded on $S_0$, it has a monotone subsequence on $S_0$, that is, a set $K_1\subseteq S_0$ such that $(a_n)$ is monotone on $K_1$. By our assumption, $K_1\notin \mathcal U$. So $S_1:=S_0\setminus K_1\in \mathcal U$.
Since $(a_n)$ is still bounded on $S_1$, we can apply the same argument again.

Hence, inductively, for all $k\in\mathbb N$, 
$$S_k:=S_0\setminus\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k K_i\right)\in\mathcal U.$$ 
So there is a decreasing chain $S_0\supsetneq S_1\supsetneq \ldots$ in $\mathcal U$.

Does that help me? I mean, is there any result stating that such a decreasing chain of sets can't be contained in $\mathcal U$? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: The chain it itself does not yield a contradiction. Also note that you didn't really make use of bounded: Any rational sequence has a monotone subsequence (if the greedy construction of an increasing/decreasing subsequence fails, the sequence is bounded from above/below)

Comment: My idea was to use boundedness by saying that there exist monotone subsequences. But I cannot prove that one of them is a subsequence whose underlying subset of $\mathbb N$ would be in $\mathcal U$. I do not see how to use "boundedness implies monotone subsequence" in another way.
Slowly I even doubt that the statement I want to prove is true. I initially wanted to show that every bounded sequence is $\mathcal U$-equal to a Cauchy sequence and thought that I can show that by finding a monotone bounded subsequence (which is always Cauchy).